# matlab complex for end loop w/ bsxfun

Tags: matlab, for-loop, bsxfun

I have a 2092x252 matrix of `double`s and need to create a `for` loop that uses the `bsxfun`. Let's just say for this example `bsxfun(@minus)`. What I need the loop to accomplish is to run `bsxfun(@minus)` using each column as an index. For example, designating column 1 as the index get the difference (using `bsxfun(@minus)`) with columns 2:252. Then set column 2 as the index and get the difference with columns 3:252 (again using `bsxfun(@minus)`). The loop has to continue to run until `bsxfun(@minus, 251, 252)`.

The output would be in one variable instead of 251 variables. There would be a total of 31626 data points.

Also, could you please explain the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, cause it results in 31626x2092 data points, but since you said to take the difference of the columns...

```
data=ceil(rand(7,5)*10); % some sample data, works with any matrix(at least 2 columns of course)

N = size(data,2);

%b=cell(N-1,1);
c=NaN(size(data,1),N*(N-1)/2); % preallocate result matrix

kk=0;
for ii=1:N-1
    %b{ii} = bsxfun(@minus,data(:,ii),data(:,ii+1:end));
    c(:,kk+(1:N-ii)) = bsxfun(@minus,data(:,ii),data(:,ii+1:end));
    kk=kk+N-ii;
end
```

Key here is that in each looping step, you select just the part of the matrix you want to perform the `minus` operation on, ie: `data(:,ii)` (= the ii'th column) and `data(:,ii+1:end)` (= all remaining columns, from the ii'th up to the end of the matrix)

The [bsxfun function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) description says:
*Apply element-by-element binary operation to two arrays with singleton expansion enabled*

That singleton expansion is what I'm using up here, bsxfun sees the two input being one column and a matrix with same sized columns, and expands the column to be same size as the matrix (=singleton expansion (row dimension gets expanded) )

So if you want the rows to be subtracted from each other, you can just provide a row and the same matrix as before, and it'll also know what to do, ie expand the row vector along the column dimension:

```
N = size(data,1);

%b=cell(N-1,1);
c=NaN(N*(N-1)/2,size(data,2)); % preallocate result matrix

kk=0;
for ii=1:N-1
    %b{ii} = bsxfun(@minus,data(ii,:),data(ii+1:end,:));
    c(kk+(1:N-ii),:) = bsxfun(@minus,data(ii,:),data(ii+1:end,:));
    kk=kk+N-ii;
end
```

As you can see, the indexing of all the matrices switched places: `A(i,j)` changed to `A(j,i)`.

Using cells for the result matrices in each step in the loop would allow easier access to the result, but since you wanted the result in one variable (matrix I assume), I commented those out.

### **EDIT**

on preallocating: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html

```
c(:,kk+(1:N-ii));
kk=kk+N-ii
```

is the indexing, which was the most tricky:

When ii=1 you have 251 columns to insert: that'll be column 1->251 in the output variable
ii=2 -> 250 columns, column 252->501 in the output
ii=3 -> 249 columns, column 502->750 in the output
ii=4 => 248 columns, column 751->999 in the output
etc.

The `kk+(1:N-ii)` is essentially doing that: selecting the appropriate columns for the output of `bsxfun`.
The variable `kk` is the number of columns already saved into the output variable `c`, so obviously it starts at zero. If you change it to another value, say `kk_init`, the first `kk_init` columns of `c` would remain empty and the resulting `c` matrix will have `N*(N-1)/2+kk_init` columns instead of `N*(N-1)/2`.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. could you further explain:       c(:,kk+(1:N-ii)),kk=kk+N-ii. And what difference does preallocating the matrix vs. not preallocating it?

Comment: one more question regarding KK, what is the purpose of setting KK=0? could you explain how matlab handles the loop when i change kk to any other number?

Comment: also, how would the code change if instead of finding the difference between columns, get the difference between rows?

Comment: Gunther, thank you for your response. I hope you don't take offense to my query, but I'm a neophyte and probably will remain one for some time. I have a bunch of matlab references which explain everything under the sun except minute details such as the one you've provided. Could you provide me with references you frequently refer to (if any)?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ is very helpfull, almost everything you'll need you can find there; you can also see that almost all links I have in my answers are to that mathwork reference library). For everything else there is SO ;)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to keep track of indices, you can compute and store the result in a cell array, then concatenate all the cells into one matrix:

```
data = rand(2092,252);
C = arrayfun(@(k) bsxfun(@minus, data(:,k), data(:,k+1:end)), ...
        1:size(data,2)-1, 'UniformOutput',false);
C = horzcat(C{:});
```

The resulting matrix:

```
>> whos C
  Name         Size                   Bytes  Class     Attributes

  C         2092x31626            529292736  double
```

Comment: thanks amro, could you explain the purpose of kk in the for loop provided by gunther?

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr.: I believe Gunther explained it very thoroughly, I don't think I have anything more to add.. Besides The whole point of using cell arrays in my answer was to avoid the tricky indexing